# Slight brown tint when starting cold water from tub faucet?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub

More specifically, when I haven't used my tub for a couple of days, and I start the water (only the cold) there is initially a bit of brown tint in it, but it rapidly disappears. It's fine if I'm using it daily. I know this is usually indicative of a pipe wearing down, but since this only happens with the initial bit of water and only on the cold side would this narrow the issue down to a piece of plumbing near the faucet? And since the tint is only slight and doesn't continue do I have more time before I would need to go in and replace something? Thanks.

Comment: It's probably rust, but without more knowledge of your plumbing there's not much we can tell you. Feel free to revise the question with more information.

Comment: @isherwood I figured it was corrosion, my question was more in regards to the hypothetical degree and location of it given the circumstances I listed.

Comment: Again, we don't know much. Could be the faucet. Could be pipes. Could be a valve. Could be a water softener.

Comment: I agree with isherwood, if you are interested in investigating further without damaging walls, try removing the trim plate from the faucet and look for black iron or galvanized pipe.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot add a comment so I’m placing it here?

If you want to try and pinpoint if it’s that single line or fixture or possibly a whole house issue. I’d start by seeing if any other locations, after sitting a couple days has this same issue or not. If the rust/corrosion still only settles at the tub fixture you would (likely) narrow down your culprit.

Im just reaching here. Is this tub at the end of the line of your plumbing? And if so are you using other water lines in the vacinity? That would keep water moving to or past the take off line to the tub? Or depending how you water lines are set up. If you have your supply line running the length of the house and 1/2” take offs from there at the room location split to the fixture. If this line to the tub is the only one coming off the supply line from the underside of it. It possibly be actaing as a rust knock out and as rust passes past this line the sediment could drop down and collect up.

If you can do some further investigating and show/explain your water supply set up and trouble shoot a tiny bit more, it would really help further narrow down a potential issue and help the community have a less broad and more informed answer. Hope this helps

Comment: great stuff. i'd like to add some unorthodox ways. - some taps allow you to remove the filter at the end of the faucet. it maybe possible to probe the pipe by extending some secured tissue (as it dissolves if trapped) to see if its rusting around the pipe.

like what papatotts says, it will be good to narrow down to the area of issue then finally investigate the piping extensions near the tap to find out which parts have actually rusted.